# Javascript to replicate placeholder functionality in input text

Tags: javascript, html

When a textbox is created, default, gray text (#888) is given a displayed. When it is given focus, the value should disappear and start showing the typed value. I've written the code for this problem and it is as follows:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Focus(i) {
            if (i.value == i.defaultValue) {
                i.value = "";
                i.style.color = "#000";
            }
        }

        function Blur(i) {
            if (i.value == "") {
                i.value = i.defaultValue;
                i.style.color = "#888";
            }
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <input type="text" name="enter firstname" title="First Name" style="color:#888;"
        value="First Name" onfocus="Focus(this)" onblur="Blur(this)" />
        <input type="text" name="enterlastname" title="Last Name" style="color:#888;"
        value="lastname" onfocus="Focus(this)" onblur="Blur(this)" />
    </body>

</html>
```

But, here whenever the textbox is focused, the value is disappearing. What should I do in order to correct this? Even though the text box is under focus, the value should not disappear and the value should disappear only when I start typing in it. I'm a new user so I can't post screenshots.

Comment: With http://jsfiddle.net/ you could get answers faster..

Comment: Firstly script tags not inside body/head elements create invalid HTML and might even cause some exceptions in some browsers.

Comment: `i.defaultValue` is undefined but I'd go for the placeholder solution => pretty easy

Comment: hey, i din het u @sujathan . What is wrong in placing script tags inside body/head??

Comment: first read the comment properly

Comment: oh yea, got it.  .
I guess i've misplaced them. Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you want is called `placeholder`.

use it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="enterfirstname" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" name="enterlastname" placeholder="Last Name" />
```

Comment: [more info](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp) about placeholder

Comment: If you want pre HTML5 support for the placeholder attribute i can recommend the jQuery Placeholder plugin (https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder).

Comment: placeholder is a good idea, but it isn't supported by IE, so he will still need something in place to accommodate for IE users.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Focus(i) {
        if (i.value == i.defaultValue) {
            i.value = "";
            i.style.color = "#000";
        }
    }

    function Blur(i) {
        if (i.value == "") {
            i.value = i.defaultValue;
            i.style.color = "#888";
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="enter firstname" title="First Name" style="color:#888;"
    value="First Name" onfocus="Focus(this)" onblur="Blur(this)" />
    <input type="text" name="enterlastname" title="Last Name" style="color:#888;"
    value="lastname" onfocus="Focus(this)" onblur="Blur(this)" />
</body>

</html>
```

Note:script tags not inside body/head elements create invalid HTML

Comment: I did not get what i expected. Please refer this link, It shows my quetion
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/contribute/
Under, WANT TO HELP, the text box has my question

Answer (score 0):

Try using "onkeydown" as following...

```
function Focus(cntrl,value)
{
    if (cntrl.value == value)
    {
       cntrl.value           = '';
       cntrl.style.color     = '#000';
    }
} 
function Blur(cntrl,value)
{
    if (cntrl.value == '') 
    {
       cntrl.style.color     = 'gray';
       cntrl.value           = value;                         
    }
}

<body>
     <input type="text" name="enter firstname" title="First Name" style="color:#888;"      value="First Name" onkeydown="Focus(this,'First Name')" onblur="Blur(this,'First Name')" />
     <input type="text" name="enterlastname" title="Last Name" style="color:#888;"      value="lastname" onkeydown="Focus(this,'lastname')" onblur="Blur(this,'lastname')" />
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer, but when the cursor is placed, the cursor is at last position, i.e at last letter. What should i do, to place the cursor at the 1st position